# Passing data from component a to b in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass data from component a to b, first `HTTP` request gives me an `Id` which I require for component b to construct another `HTTP` request.

Component A

```
@Component({
    selector: 'movielist',
    templateUrl: './app/movie.components/movie-list/movie.view.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MovieService, CoreService],
    directives: [MovieDetailComponent]
})
export class MovieComponent {
@ViewChild(MovieDetailComponent) movieDetail:MovieDetailComponent
getMovies () {
        this.movieService.movieRes()
            .subscribe(movie => {
                for (var i = 0; i < movie.results.length; i++) {
                    this.movieId = movie.results[i].id;
                    this.getMovieDetail(this.movieId);
                }
            });
    }
 ngOnInit() {
   this.getMovies();
 }
}
```

Component B

```
getMovieDetail (movieId:any) {
    this.movieService.movieDetail(movieId)
        .subscribe(details => {
            console.log(details)
        })
}
```

my Service to construct 2nd `HTTP` request looks like

```
movieDetail (movieId: any) {
    return this.http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + movieId + '?api_key=' + this.apiKey)
    .map (res => res.json())
}
```

I tried using `@ViewChild` but when I initialise `getMovieDetail` in component B I get an error of `getMovieDetail` undefined.

How can I pass `movieId` from component A to B? Not sure if using `@ViewChild` is the right way, if so, I'm probably doing something wrong how I use `@ViewChild`.

Comment: `@ViewChild()` only initializes after `ngAfterViewInit()` is called. From your code it's not clear where and when `getMovies()` is called. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html or component communication.

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to mention in my above post, `getMovies()` is being called on `ngInit`.

Comment: You have `ViewChild` in component A but mention that you used it in component B. How are component A and B related in DOM? (direct parent-child or not, which one is parent).

Comment: `getMovies` would be the parent as that's where the `id` is coming from so `getMovies` triggers first. I'm going to construct `a href` something like `<a href="www.site.com/movie/{{ id-of-thor }}/...> Thor </a>` which then use the template use in component B.

Comment: Have you tried moving `this.getMovies()` to `ngAfterViewInit()` as suggested in my first comment?